# Closed form of an infinite sum

Tags: probability, summation

What is the closed form expression of the following infinite sum 
$$ \sum_{i = 1}^\infty (rp)^{i-1} q^{\tfrac{1}{2}i(i-1)},$$
where $p + q = 1$, $p\ge 0$ and $q \ge 0$ ?

Comment: Quite hopeless I guess. Even summing $p^{i^2}$ will involve the elliptic theta function (by wolfram alpha)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $rp=1$ it's (in Maple's notation) $$ \frac{\Theta_2(0,\sqrt{q})}{2 q^{1/8}}$$
where $\Theta_2$ is a Jacobi theta function.